# Script is breaking when I call .html() function

Tags: jquery, html, jscript

I can't figure out what is going on here. when I move the line "$("#mc").html(newdivid);"  to the beginning of the function (above the .clone() staement) it works but the rest of the function wont work. If I move this line to the end, like it is now, the rest of the function works but this line wont work. I am confused.

```
<html>

<head>

    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var newdiv;

        var divcntr = 1;

        var newdivid;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#clone_button').click(function(){

                newdivid = divcntr++;

                //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box

                $("#origdiv").clone().appendTo('.maincontainer');

                newdiv = $('.maincontainer').children().last();

                newdiv.setAttribute("id", newdivid);

                $("#mc").html(newdivid);

            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="button" value="Clone box" class="button" id="clone_button"/>

    <input type="button" value="Extra button" class="button" id="std_button" />

    <div class="internal" id="origdiv"></div>

    <div class="maincontainer" id="mc">sdfgdfg</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my css...

```
.maincontainer {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.internal {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}

#clone_button {
    background-color: blue;
}

#std_button {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: you're calling `setAttribute` on a jQuery object, but it's a dom method

Comment: Could you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: @BravoZulu Sorry, How do I add the HTML?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I posted all of my code does this help? also I am using Adobe Brackets for an editor and Chrome as a live link.

Comment: Used your code and created and Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcq5sogw/1/) with the same edits proposed by me and @TJCrowder and it is working fine here.

Comment: So now I see you are trying to update 2 things in #mc container. One is you are creating and appending a clone of #origdiv and then changing the html of #mc to newdivid. Apparently, the clone you have created for #origdiv is getting overridden by newdivid. What exactly are you trying to put in #mc container?

Comment: @King Size I am trying to have it display the value of "newdivid"

Comment: Then why are you cloning #origdiv ? Additionally, did you see the fiddle, does it work for you?

Comment: @King Size 47 I am trying to create a function that will read fields from a database and display them in a grid layout on a page/form with Tilte, Desc, Username, an Img etc... Eventually I will replace the button with an "if exist" loop to read the database. I am only displaying the "newdivid" for testing. I will check out the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that's wrong is this line:

```
newdiv.setAttribute("id", newdivid);
```

In your code, `newdiv` refers to a jQuery object, not a DOM element, and jQuery objects don't have a `setAttribute` method. They have an `attr` method:

```
newdiv.attr("id", newdivid);
```

---

There are several other things you can do to improve that code, such as:

- Scoping the variables only to where they're needed, no broader
- Using the reference to the cloned element you already have rather than looking it up with `.children().last()`
- Indenting the code readably

For instance:

```
var divcntr = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#clone_button').click(function() {
        var newdivid = divcntr++;

        $("#origdiv").clone()
            .attr("id", newdivid)
            .appendTo('.maincontainer');

        $("#mc").html(newdivid);
    });
});
```

Also note that while all-digits `id` values are perfectly valid, they're awkward if you ever need to use them in CSS selectors. You might consider changing

```
.attr("id", newdivid)
```

to

```
.attr("id", "x" + newdivid)
```

...or similar, to make life easier, **if** you're ever going to use those `id` values in CSS selectors.

---

**Live Example:**

```js
var divcntr = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#clone_button').click(function() {
    var newdivid = divcntr++;

    $("#origdiv").clone()
      .attr("id", newdivid)
      .appendTo('.maincontainer');

    $("#mc").html(newdivid);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="origdiv">This is the div that gets cloned</div>
<hr>
<div class="maincontainer">
  This is the container the divs end up in
</div>
<hr>
<input type="button" id="clone_button" value="Clone">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Re your updated question where you posted the HTML: **Of course** the

```
$("#mc").html(newdivid);
```

line is going to wipe out the cloned div: You've appended the cloned div to `.maincontainer`, which is `#mc`. If you'd used the same selector for that element in both places you refer to it, that woudl have been clear from the start.

If you want a counter at the top of `.maincontainer`, you'll need to put it in a child element, like this:

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div id="mc"></div>
    sdfgdfg
 </div>
```

Now, `#mc` and `.maincontainer` don't refer to the same element anymore, and you can overwrite the content of `#mc` without also overwriting `.maincontainer`'s contents. :-)

Here's a working copy your code, with **only** the `.attr` correction and the `#mc`/`.maincontainer` thing fixed:

```js
var newdiv;

var divcntr = 1;

var newdivid;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#clone_button').click(function() {

    newdivid = divcntr++;

    //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box

    $("#origdiv").clone().appendTo('.maincontainer');

    newdiv = $('.maincontainer').children().last();

    newdiv.attr("id", newdivid);

    $("#mc").html(newdivid);

  });
});
```

```css
.maincontainer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.internal {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
#clone_button {
  background-color: blue;
}
#std_button {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Clone box" class="button" id="clone_button" />

<input type="button" value="Extra button" class="button" id="std_button" />

<div class="internal" id="origdiv"></div>

<div class="maincontainer">
  <div id="mc"></div>
  sdfgdfg
</div>
```

Comment: It works! thank you very much for your help! I did not realize that changing the HTML of a div wiped out all of the information in the div, I thought it would only change the HTML and leave everything else alone. That actually answers a couple of other questions for me as well! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

First thing is you are working on a jQuery object to set attribute. You need to use it as an html object and then use the property "attr" to set the id attribute. like below:
    var newdiv;

```
var divcntr = 1;

var newdivid;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#clone_button').click(function(){

newdivid = divcntr++;

$("#origdiv").clone().appendTo('.maincontainer');

newdiv = $('.maincontainer').children().last();
$(newdiv).attr("id", newdivid);


$("#mc").html(newdivid);

});
});
```

Comment: I have changed onlye one line of your code newdiv.setAttribute("id", newdivid);
 to $(newdiv).attr("id", newdivid);
And this seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Posting a duplicate of [an answer from 10 minutes earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31748580/1) isn't useful. After posting, look around to see if you're just duplicating (much) earlier information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I understand what you say. But there are always multiple ways of getting about a thing. You proposed different edits and I proposed different. Sometimes its easy to understand with lesser edits than more. Was just trying to help in the easiest way. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: would you now be able to remove your downvote? thanks.

Comment: Ok I posted the entire index.php and my css. I tried changing the line as you did and its not working. Could it be that I am using Adobe Brackets and live testing in Chrome?

Comment: No, not different things. Exactly the same thing: Changing `.setAttribute` to `.attr`.

Comment: *"would you now be able to remove your downvote"* Never assume that the person engaging with you is also the person who downvoted. You'll be wrong more often than right.